# Getting a response in a click from an email campaign - how?

Tags: email, flow, process-builder, campaign

We are going to target some thousands of leads from 3rd party marketing software.

Instead of a form to fill, when sending the email, we know exactly who gets the email. Is it possible, using a link, hidden field, or whatever solution, that once the lead/recipient clicked on the 'click me button' on the email, that it will notify the lead owner + update the SF campaign with an action?

I thought of using a VF page on a site, that will simply get the lead ID, and trigger the flow/process builder from there.

ideas?

Comment: and the third party marketing software doesn't have an existing integration with SFDC to notify of email campaign responses?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly, but I'd expect it'd depends on where the link takes the recipient. **I'll assume this takes them to your company's website, say, to advertise something?**

> Is it possible, using a link, hidden field, or whatever solution, that once the lead/recipient clicked on the 'click me button' on the email, that it will notify the lead owner + update the SF campaign with an action?

You'd definitely want to pass in some parameters which your 3rd Party provider should allow, probably just the Id of the lead would do. Something like...

```
mycompany.com/mypage?leadid=abc123
```

... Would be enough. When the user lands on that particular page, you could then check for the existence of that parameter and either use a REST or SOAP call to your Org to run an update query on the record that's passed into that parameter.

You could then even use a Workflow to manage the e-mails being sent to your colleagues that would notify them that the contact related to the lead has clicked the link that updated a particular field.

> I thought of using a VF page on a site, that will simply get the lead ID, and trigger the flow/process builder from there.

I appreciate this is basically the same thing you've suggested here, you could do this using a publicly accessible Visualforce page too although I'd expect you'd get more value from directing them to your website giving them chance to browse other products and services you offer.